# Grant access to gitlab-ci runners

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have 2 projects in gitlab. For the examples purpose lets call them `foo/main` and `foo/dep`.

In `foo/main` I am using gitlab-ci with a docker-runner running on another machine to execute automated tests and builds.

As `foo/dep` is a dependency for `foo/main` I need to git clone it while building main.

Both repositories are private/have restricted access.

How can I grant access to the docker-runner to that other repo?

Currently I am receiving a:

```
npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [GitLab CI runner - can't access other repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36571673/gitlab-ci-runner-cant-access-other-repository) you could expose your own .ssh-keys to the docker-container via the `gitlab-runner/config.toml`.

I hope that is not the only solution as it might be unsafe to expose the keys to whatever somebody pushes into a repo.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the `Settings` on top right of the project container below your profile picture. Then choose `Deploy Keys` section and add your `ssh public key` of your computers to the project.
for more info about generating `ssh key` refere to https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

Comment: That still requires all machines running ci to 1st: have a private key and 2nd: To expose that private key to the docker-container. It's the same answer as mine